# What would be my affiliation if I'm a Masters student?

Tags: affiliation

The question title pretty much says it all. I'm now a graduate student pursuing my Masters degree. Will the university I'm enrolled in be my affiliation when writing a paper?

Comment: Well, what else would it be?

Comment: @Eppicurt - Thanks. This is my first time writing a paper, so I’m just making sure. Have a good day :)

Comment: I've seen several math papers in recent years (in MAA journals) in which one or more of the authors is a high school student, and their high schools are listed for their affiliation, and I thought nothing of it besides being impressed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

And be sure to get it in there before you graduate. Though if you are not moving straight to another uni and plan on publishing more, if you talk to your prof they might hook you up with "affiliate" status. This means no money or much of anything else other than the ability to claim affiliation.

Comment: At least from my experience it is pretty common to use the affiliation at the time the research was conducted and not necessarely the one at the time the manuscript was submitted.